# Why Solaiman bin Dawud (a.s.) is the last prophet who enters the heaven?

Tags: jannah, prophet-sulayman

I have heard that it has been narrated from Imam Jafar Sadiq (peace be upon him) as the sixth Imam of Shia Islam that he said:

> Solaiman bin Dawood (a.s.) is the last prophet who enters the heaven
>   (Jannah).

But I wonder what the reason is that he will enter the heaven as the last prophet?

Comment: Can you provide a reference/link to the source of this narration?

Comment: I've got its related source/link --but is in Farsi [Persian]: 
And . ابن همام اسکافی، محمد بن همام، التمحیص، ص 49، قم، مدرسة الإمام المهدی(عج)، چاپ اول، 1404ق.
. یعقوبی، احمد بن أبی یعقوب‏، تاریخ الیعقوبی، ج ‏2، ص 96، بیروت، دار صادر، چاپ اول، بی‌تا. -------------------------------------- in the following site: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa70886

Comment: God willing, it helps you, to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

***In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful***

In regards to the query that:

> Why Solaiman bin Dawud(a.s.) is the last prophet who enters the
> heaven?

Briefly speaking, the response can be related to the properties and the equipment which Solaiman bin Dawud  (a.s.) had. As a consequence, he will has a long audit because of them (in compare with other prophets). Therefore that’s why he is the last prophet who enters the heaven.

***Source Books:***

> 1 - داستان‌های صاحبدلان، ج 2، ص 65
>
> 2 - بحارالانوار، ج 73، ص 81
>
> 3 - پندهای جاویدان، ص 167
>
> 4 - حیوةالقلوب، ج 1، ص 370

---

Reference link:

- [www.isna.ir/fa/news](https://www.isna.ir/news/92021509565/%DA%86%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%B3%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B9-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA-%DA%A9%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%B4%D8%AA-%D9%85%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF)

Answer (score 0):

I actually heard this in one lecture on YouTube. The guy who was holding the lecture said that Sulayman (a.s.) will be the last among the prophets to enter heaven because of all of the things and abilities he got from Allah (s.w.t) in this world.

But this is just something that I heard, and Allah (s.w.t) knows best.